# Webpack - React: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack

1. I built the NPM package based on components written in React and Typescript.
2. Export that package as npm
3. Install package into another React with TS repo

Result: Error appear:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./node_modules/@nikolatrajkovic123/ec-general-section-form/HubSectionPack.tsx
> 10:5 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:5) You may need an
> appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
> configured to process this file. See
> https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders | import
> './package-styles.scss'; |
>
> > type HubSectionPackProps = { |   sectionName: SectionName; |   // eslint-disable-next-line

Babel

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react", "env", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

Webpack:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.tsx',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|ts|tsx)$/,
        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
        options: {
          customize: require.resolve(
            'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides',
          ),
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          'style-loader',
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.scss'],
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.CleanPlugin()],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

Package.json of the package:

```
{
  "name": "@nikolatrajkovic123/hub-section-form",
  "version": "1.3.8",
  "description": "Enrollment / Hub section form",
  "main": "./index.ts",
  "module": "./dist/index.es.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Bestowinc/enrollment-client.git"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
  },
  "author": "Direct Team",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@bestowinc/bestow-logger": "1.0.26",
    "@bestowinc/enroll-sdk-core": "^0.9.40",
    "@bestowinc/kindred-ds": "^0.6.2",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.7.1",
    "@sentry/minimal": "^6.14.1",
    "@sentry/react": "^6.3.6",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^6.3.6",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@tippyjs/react": "^4.2.5",
    "@types/react-slider": "^1.3.1",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "@xstate/inspect": "^0.4.1",
    "@xstate/react": "^1.3.1",
    "auth0-js": "^9.16.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "cleave.js": "^1.6.0",
    "fast-glob": "^3.2.7",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "ismobilejs": "^1.1.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
    "lodash.merge": "^4.6.2",
    "lodash.noop": "^3.0.1",
    "lodash.unset": "^4.5.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "postcss": "^8.3.11",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "postcss-scss": "^3.0.4",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.15.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-slider": "^1.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.2",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat",
    "tippy.js": "^6.3.1",
    "tsconfig": "^7.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
    "xstate": "^4.17.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.4",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.0",
    "@bestowinc/xray-test-util": "^1.1.4",
    "@craco/craco": "^6.1.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.3.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^21.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "^4.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.1.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-replace": "^3.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-url": "^6.1.0",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/auth0-js": "^9.14.2",
    "@types/chance": "^1.1.1",
    "@types/cleave.js": "^1.4.4",
    "@types/history": "4.7.9",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.19",
    "@types/lodash.get": "^4.4.6",
    "@types/lodash.merge": "^4.6.6",
    "@types/lodash.noop": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/lodash.pick": "^4.4.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.9",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.7",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "@types/react-slider": "^1.3.1",
    "@types/segment-analytics": "^0.0.34",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.15",
    "@types/styled-system": "^5.1.13",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.15.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.15.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.13.3",
    "chance": "^1.1.7",
    "circle-github-bot": "^2.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "cypress": "9.0.0",
    "cypress-terminal-report": "^3.3.4",
    "eslint": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.3.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.11.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^9.10.2",
    "husky": "^6.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "luxon": "^1.26.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.6",
    "neat-csv": "^6.0.1",
    "pdf-parse": "^1.1.1",
    "prettier": "2.2.1",
    "progress-bar-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "rollup": "^2.38.4",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.4.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-svg": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^3.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-url-resolve": "^0.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "10.1.1",
    "sinon": "^9.2.4",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "4.2.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "tslib": "2.3.1"
  },
  "external": [
    "react",
    "react-dom"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "rollup -c  --watch",
    "build": "rollup -c"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/readme"
}
```

Comment: can you share package.json of npm package and app from where you are trying to consume?

Comment: @RahulSharma yeah, I updated the post with package.json of the package.

Comment: Package.json main should be js file. because when you compile ts it becomes js.

Comment: I personally use nx it comes with multiple options. you can also create an example app and storybook along with a package
https://nx.dev